# String.endIndex incrementing error

Tags: swift, string

I have a case like that:

```
var fieldName = "VERSION"
var versionField = "VERSION:4.1"

var version = versionField.substringFromIndex(fieldName.endIndex.successor())
```

The last line generate a runtime error "fatal error: cannot increment endIndex". It's happen because swift doesn't know what the next index after biggest one. Looks like this solution works for swift 1.* only. But is there any way to solve this issue succinctly for new swift version?
Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems:

- `fieldName.endIndex` is the "one past the end" position of the string,
  it has no successor.
- You must not use the index of one string as the subscript for
  a different string. That *may* work in some cases, but can
  crash with a runtime exception if the strings contain 
  characters outside of the "basic multilingual plane" (Emojis, flags, ...).

A working variant would be (*Swift 2.2*):

```
let fieldName = "VERSION:"
let versionField = "VERSION:4.1"

if versionField.hasPrefix(fieldName) {
    let version = versionField.substringFromIndex(
        versionField.startIndex.advancedBy(fieldName.characters.count))
    print(version) // 4.1
} else {
    print("No version found")
}
```

or alternatively:

```
if let range = versionField.rangeOfString(fieldName)
    where range.startIndex == versionField.startIndex {
    let version = versionField.substringFromIndex(range.endIndex)
    print(version) // 4.1
} else {
    print("No version found")
}
```

You can remove the constraint

```
where range.startIndex == versionField.startIndex
```

if the field should be found anywhere in the string.

*Swift 3:*

```
if versionField.hasPrefix(fieldName) {
    let version = versionField.substring(
        from: versionField.index(versionField.startIndex, offsetBy: fieldName.characters.count))
    print(version) // 4.1
} else {
    print("No version found")
}
```

or alternatively,

```
if let range = versionField.range(of: fieldName),
    range.lowerBound == versionField.startIndex {
    let version = versionField.substring(from: range.upperBound)
    print(version) // 4.1
} else {
    print("No version found")
}
```

Comment: Note that OP has `"fieldName = "VERSION"` not `fieldName = "VERSION:"` so I guess it should be `let version = versionField.substringFromIndex(range.endIndex.advancedBy(1))` right?

Comment: @EricAya: I changed that on purpose to simplify the code. `range.endIndex.advancedBy(1)` could be past the end of `versionField`, so you would have to check that first. Also it would not verify that the version field is followed by a colon.